# the reindex method in Tire gem

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I am going through the tire gem(using it as an Elsaticsearch client) library,especially the reindex method . Here is the link to the ruby script:
   **https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb**

So here is the reindex method in the tire gem.

```
def reindex(name, options={}, &block)
  new_index = Index.new(name)
  new_index.create(options) unless new_index.exists?

  transform = options.delete(:transform)

  Search::Scan.new(self.name, &block).each do |results|

    documents = results.map do |document|
      document  = document.to_hash.except(:type, :_index, :_explanation, :_score, :_version, :highlight, :sort)
      document  = transform.call(document) if transform
      document
    end

    new_index.bulk_store documents
  end
end
```

I get whole scrolling and scanning concept in order to do reindexing. But what I am not able to understand is the transform option in the above method.

What does this:

```
transform = options.delete(:transform)
```

and this:

```
document  = transform.call(document) if transform
```

achieve?

Can anybody provide an example or a use case on how to use the :transform option?